# Were Geordi's ocular implants in First Contact those he talked about with Dr Pulaski?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In one of the earlier episodes in TNG series 2, Dr Pulaski talks to Geordi about not having to wear a visor and using ocular implants instead.  We notice he has ocular implants in *First Contact* onwards, so are these the implants Pulaski talked to him about?

Comment: Is there any reason not to think so?

Comment: It's just that it took another 7 or so years for him to proceed with that, and he upgraded his visor in the mean time.  I also got the impression (I don't know why) that they were talking about organic ones, but I think this is wrong.

Comment: Weren't there risks involved with the implants when Pulaski suggested them, that might have left him blind if it failed?  Might be he just didn't want to take the risk until the procedure was better.  (I think he did tell her something at the end of the episode, can't remember what it was, though)

Comment: @Izkata - I remember now: that's right!  So, is the procedure he undertook between FC and end of TNG this same, improved procedure, or was it a different one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that they are the same implants. The ones that Pulaski mentioned would have reduced Geordi's visual ability, which he appeared concerned about, by 20%. This option was quickly followed up by Pulaksi's offer to replace the visor with real eyes, which is the procedure that had the risk James mentioned.

> [Sickbay]
>   (Geordi is having a check-up on his implants)
>   PULASKI: It's possible to install optical devices which look like normal eyes, and would still give you about the same visual range as the visor.
>   LAFORGE: Done? You say almost. How much reduction?
>   PULASKI: Twenty percent. There is another option. I can attempt to regenerate your optic nerve, and, with the help of the replicator, fashion normal eyes. You would see like everyone else.
>   LAFORGE: Wait a minute. I was told that was impossible.
>   PULASKI: I've done it twice, in situations somewhat similar to yours. Geordi, it would eliminate the constant pain you are under. Why are you hesitating?
>   LAFORGE: Well, when I came to see you, it was to talk about modifying this. And now you're saying it could be possible for me to have normal vision?
>   PULASKI: Yes.
>   LAFORGE: I don't know. I'd be giving up a lot.
>   PULASKI: There's something else you must know. This is a one shot. If you decide to change your mind, there's no going back. And there are risks. I can offer choices, not guarantees.
>   LAFORGE: Well, this is a lot to think about. I'll get back to you, Doctor. Thank you.
>   <sub>[Loud as a Whisper](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/132.htm)</sub>

Geordi responds by saying he'd have to think about it and would follow up later, which presumably happened off screen. Since he did not get new implants or eyes during the show, we must assume he was unhappy with either option available at the time. For him to show up in First Contact with the implants suggests that something had changed; probably a combination of his opinion (his visor was hacked for a second time in Generations) and the technology available in the implants.

Comment: As a sidenote, we see in First Contact that his new implants most likely have the same (or even better) functionality. He checks a copper coil pretty similar as he does in the show sometimes (seeming to see things we can't) and can even zoom and see heat signatures (when chasing Cochrane). So we can assume that these implants where superior to the Visor or at least as good. In Insurrection there's a short mentioning of the implants, though it doesn't make it clear if they still cause pain or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Memory Alpha* in the entries for [ocular implants](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ocular_implant), [Dr Pulaski](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Katherine_Pulaski), and [La Forge](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Geordi_La_Forge) himself, yes, these are the same implants. It does not cite any sources though, so it would appear that the authors of all three articles have simply assumed that the operation is the same. A quick check of other *Star Trek* sites has revealed no interviews with LeVar Burton or anyone else about this issue, so it looks like it's merely conjecture at this point.

I would assume that Izkata is correct; Geordi wanted the implants, but was unwilling to undergo the risks associated with them at that time. As the medical science advanced, he felt willing to undergo the smaller risk at a later date.